# Enabling Client Side Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to know that if it is possible to enable JavaScript on client side browser e.g if most of the functionality of my website is characterized by JavaScript and some of the viewers of my website have disabled JavaScript, how can I enable it rather then the client is asked to turn JavaScript on? Is that possible? Any alternative like my code will check if JavaScript is enabled or disabled on client's browser and if it is disabled then i will request the client with an alert message or something to turn it on to see my website's full functionality ?

Comment: that would be so awesome :D

Comment: you have to be chuck norris to let that happen

Comment: I hope it's not possible. The user made a choice. If you were able to just blow that away, that choice would be meaningless. It's "disable javascript", not "disable javascript unless someone really wants to enable it"

Comment: Jon Skeet is the only one that can do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned it is not possible. This would be a massive security risk if you were able to change the browser settings via code.

You have a couple of options. Provide alternative functionality for users who have JavaScript disabled, or make use of a `<noscript>` block.

```
<noscript>
    <p>This application requires that JavaScript is enabled. </p>
    <p>Please follow these instructions on how to enable JavaScript [link to some document].</p>     
    <p>Please also check out the advantages of enabling JavaScript [link to some document explaining why people should enable]</p>
</noscript>
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative :-)

Comment: If you really want to force a user to enable JavaScript, but a `<div />` within the `<noscript>`. Style the `<div />` to be 100% width and height of the screen with a white background, then have the text on that. This means that they are unable to actually attempt to use anything within the site unless then enable JS.

Answer (score 1):

If something is *disabled* or *not available*, then by definition you cannot turn it on or make it available. Then there would be no point in turning it off in the first place.

Which is a long winded way to say: no, it's not possible.

Do show some message when Javascript is *disabled*, you use [the `<noscript>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/noscript).

Answer (score 0):

It  is not possible to do that `ENABLE`.You can not override the browser settings

Answer (score 0):

No. You can't. Only you can detect whether javascript is enabled or not. since it is browser's security concern, you can not enable javascript from the javascript code ...